# Get max characters count among multiple text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to get the max characters among the below input box while typing and apply font size for all the boxes based on that characters length.

```
<input type="text" class="engrave-input" placeholder="Line 1">
<input type="text" class="engrave-input" placeholder="Line 2">
<input type="text" class="engrave-input" placeholder="Line 3">
<input type="text" class="engrave-input" placeholder="Line 4">
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. What have you tried?

Comment: In addition to @jens statement, can you please edit your question for clarity, the outcome is not super defined. What is the max number of characters? what are the constraints?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Loop your input fields and compare each one and get the maximum count of the textbox value like below.

```js
var count = 0;
$('button#max').on('click', function(){
  $('.engrave-input').each(function(){
     count = $(this).val().length > count ? $(this).val().length : count;
  });
  alert(count);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="engrave-input" placeholder="Line 1">
<input type="text" class="engrave-input" placeholder="Line 2">
<input type="text" class="engrave-input" placeholder="Line 3">
<input type="text" class="engrave-input" placeholder="Line 4">

<button id="max">
Get Max
</button>
```